# How to install firebird client into the GAC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I have a readme txt file todo same steps, and it says to me:

> Install FirebirdClient into the GAC You can use gacutil utility to do
>   this or to check whether it's correctly installed. The gacutil show
>   you also the signature for assembly, that will be used later.

I am neophyte at this world so i didn't understand what it is, and I can't speak English very well.
Can you explain to me in a simple way (with simple words) what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the following link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx

> To install a strong-named assembly into the global assembly cache
>   using the Global Assembly Cache tool (Gacutil.exe)
>
> At the command prompt, type the following command:
>
> gacutil -i
>
> In this command, assembly name is the name of the assembly to install
>   in the global assembly cache.
>
> The following example installs an assembly with the file name
>   hello.dll into the global assembly cache.

```
gacutil -i hello.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx)

Use the command

```
gacutil -i <assembly name>
```